# Gremlin: Get All Routes from point A to point B with Day as the only constraint

Tags: algorithm, gremlin, graph-databases, amazon-neptune

I'm attempting to create a route optimizer, the end state will eventually optimize the routes based on certain parameters, right now I'm just trying to get a graph DB set up and a query that can get me the information I need in an quick manner. The information I need is basically a list of flights from point A to point B.

I completely based my graph model off of this [blog](https://maxdemarzi.com/2017/05/24/flight-search-with-neo4j/), while removing the things that I will not use in my model (distance)

[image]

This is an example of my input data

```
~id,origin:String,destination:String,carrier:String,start_datetime:Date,end_datetime:Date
ZZ0001MIA20230612,MIA,ATL,ZZ,2023-06-12T09:10:00Z,2023-06-12T11:00:00Z
ZZ0002IND20230612,IND,PHX,ZZ,2023-06-12T09:20:00Z,2023-06-12T13:00:00Z
ZZ0003TPA20230612,TPA,DEN,ZZ,2023-06-12T09:20:00Z,2023-06-12T16:42:00Z
ZZ0004FLL20230612,FLL,ATL,ZZ,2023-06-12T09:35:00Z,2023-06-12T11:25:00Z
ZZ0005FLL20230612,FLL,DAL,ZZ,2023-06-12T09:45:00Z,2023-06-12T16:55:00Z
ZZ0006MDW20230612,MDW,PHX,ZZ,2023-06-12T10:00:00Z,2023-06-12T15:27:00Z
```

Here is the script to add the data into TinkerPop

```py
import csv
from collections import defaultdict
from datetime import datetime

from gremlin_python.driver.driver_remote_connection import DriverRemoteConnection
from gremlin_python.process.graph_traversal import __
from gremlin_python.process.traversal import T
from gremlin_python.structure.graph import Graph


def read_flight_data(file_name):
    with open(file_name, 'r') as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file)
        fieldnames = next(reader)
        fieldnames = [name.split(":")[0] for name in fieldnames]
        for row in reader:
            yield dict(zip(fieldnames, row))

graph = Graph()
g = graph.traversal().withRemote(DriverRemoteConnection('ws://localhost:8182/gremlin','g'))  # replace with your Gremlin Server URI

def create_vertices(flight_data_file):
    print("Creating vertices for airports...")
    flight_data = list(read_flight_data(flight_data_file))

    # create vertices for airports
    airports = set(flight['origin'] for flight in flight_data).union(
        set(flight['destination'] for flight in flight_data))
    for code in airports:
        g.addV('Airport').property(T.id, code).property('code', code).iterate()

    print("Creating vertices for airport days...")
    # create vertices for airport days
    airport_days = defaultdict(set)
    for flight in flight_data:
        start_date = datetime.strptime(flight['start_datetime'], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ').date()
        end_date = datetime.strptime(flight['end_datetime'], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ').date()
        airport_days[flight['origin']].add(start_date)
        airport_days[flight['destination']].add(end_date)
    for airport, dates in airport_days.items():
        for date in dates:
            g.addV('AirportDay').property(T.id, f'{airport}_{date}').property('key', f'{airport}_{date}').property('date', f'{date}').iterate()

    print("Creating vertices for flights...")
    # create vertices for flights
    for flight in flight_data:
        g.addV('Flight').property(T.id, flight['~id']).property('code', flight['~id']).property('departs', flight['start_datetime']).property('arrives', flight['end_datetime']).iterate()

def create_edges(flight_data_file):
    print("Creating FLIES_TO edges...")
    flight_data = list(read_flight_data(flight_data_file))

    # create FLIES_TO edges
    for flight in flight_data:
        g.V(flight['origin']).addE('FLIES_TO').to(__.V(flight['destination'])).iterate()

    print("Creating HAS_DAY edges...")
    # create HAS_DAY edges
    airport_days = defaultdict(set)
    for flight in flight_data:
        start_date = datetime.strptime(flight['start_datetime'], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ').date()
        end_date = datetime.strptime(flight['end_datetime'], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ').date()
        airport_days[flight['origin']].add(start_date)
        airport_days[flight['destination']].add(end_date)
    for airport, dates in airport_days.items():
        for date in dates:
            g.V(airport).addE('HAS_DAY').to(__.V(f'{airport}_{date}')).iterate()

    print("Creating FLIGHT edges...")
    # create FLIGHT edges
    for flight in flight_data:
        start_date = datetime.strptime(flight['start_datetime'], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ').date()
        end_date = datetime.strptime(flight['end_datetime'], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ').date()
        g.V(f'{flight["origin"]}_{start_date}').addE(f'{flight["destination"]}_FLIGHT').to(__.V(flight['~id'])).iterate()
        g.V(flight['~id']).addE(f'{flight["destination"]}_FLIGHT').to(__.V(f'{flight["destination"]}_{end_date}')).iterate()


def clear_graph():
    g.V().drop().iterate()
    g.E().drop().iterate()

clear_graph()
# use the functions
create_vertices('flights.csv')
create_edges('flights.csv')
```

This is the first query that I had, this just loops through the airports in order to determine if an airport flies from one to another.

```py
from gremlin_python.process.graph_traversal import __
from gremlin_python.structure.graph import Graph
from gremlin_python.driver.driver_remote_connection import DriverRemoteConnection
import time

graph = Graph()
g = graph.traversal().withRemote(DriverRemoteConnection('ws://localhost:8182/gremlin','g'))  # replace with your Gremlin Server URI

start = time.time()

paths = g.V().hasLabel('Airport').has('code', 'MIA')\
    .repeat(__.out('FLIES_TO')).emit().times(3).simplePath()\
    .has('code', 'ATL').path().by('code').toList()

end = time.time()

# convert to set to remove duplicates
unique_paths = set(tuple(path) for path in paths)

# sort paths by length
sorted_paths = sorted(unique_paths, key=len)

# print out the unique paths
for path in sorted_paths:
    print(path)

print(len(sorted_paths))

# Calculate the time taken in milliseconds
time_taken_ms = (end - start) * 1000
```

This was taking about 2 seconds with 50k records.

This second query was meant to find valid flight routes from the MIA airport to the ATL airport on the date 2023-06-12 while making sure that all airports along the path have AirportDay vertices representing the desired date.

```py
desired_date = '2023-06-12'

paths = g.V().hasLabel('Airport').has('code', 'MIA') \
    .where(__.out('HAS_DAY').has('date', P.eq(desired_date))) \
    .repeat(
        __.out('FLIES_TO').where(
            __.out('HAS_DAY').has('date', P.eq(desired_date))
        ).simplePath()
    ).emit().times(3) \
    .has('code', 'ATL').where(
        __.out('HAS_DAY').has('date', P.eq(desired_date))
    ) \
    .path().by('code').toList()
```

I was under the impression that this one would be faster, but for some reason this one is taking about 7 seconds with 50k records.

Unfortunately this is just to get the actual routes from airport to airport and does not actually include the flight id, eventually i will need it to list all of the possible routes from point A to point B with a maximum of 4 stops, the 4th stop being the destination (right now my queries hang with 50k records with both of the above queries).

I'm not quite sure where to go next in terms of improving the performance, it sounds like based on the blog post this method of modeling routes should be extremely efficient but it is not working for me... Eventually this will have about 1.5mil records...

Comment: Your performance is dependent on the performance of your database engine. It looks like you are using a database based in the cloud.  Getting data out of the cloud is very slow, several milliseconds for the simplest query.  In all probability, you will have to download the data you need to local memory, then do the queries.

Comment: I plan to use AWS Neptune, but for right now I'm using TinkerPop on my local machine to build out the queries first.

Comment: I am not familiar with those engines.  AWS is going to be a LOT slower than something running locally.  So if the performance already fails to meet your requirements, you are going to have to rethink your design.

Comment: Hi - happy to try to help but it looks like the sample code also needs a CSV file. Are you able to perhaps provide a small subset of the data as `addV` and `addE` steps to facilitate writing a few queries and testing them.

Comment: DId you build an index on the `code` property? Btw, the csv file is provided above the sample code.